# NunitをVisual Studio上以外でも動かしたい

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

c#のコードをNunit（ver3.5）を用いてwindows 10のvisual studio 2015上で利用していますが、visual studioがインストールされていない環境（windows server 2019）でもnunitのテストコードの動作確認をしたい場合、どのようなやり方がありますでしょうか？

できればguiインターフェースがあったほうが助かりますが、コンソールによる動作確認でも構いません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Console Runner](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Runner.html)が用意されているので、[適切なコマンドライン](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html)で起動すればいいと思います。